# If $V$ has a basis of size $n$, show that any linearly independent set of size $n$ in $V$ is a basis of $V$.

Tags: vector-spaces

If $V$ has a basis of size $n$, show that any linearly independent set of size $n$ in $V$ is a basis of $V$.

I can see this is true, but don't know how to prove it, any hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you've a set with $\;n\;$ linearly independent vectors $\;B:=\{v_1,...,v_n\}\;$ , If $\;Span(B)\neq V\;$, there exists $\;v\in V\;$ s.t. $\;v\notin Span(B)\;$ . But this last is equivalent to $\;B\cup\{v\}\;$ linearly independent, which is impossible in a linear space of dimension $\;n\;$ ... Fill in details now.

Comment: thanks!! but from what you said above id also have to show that, if V vector space dimension n, then for linearly independent set S of m vectors where m<=n there exists another set R of n-m vectors such that              S$\cup$R=basis of V ?

Comment: @Rivaldo Well, what you seem to mean is a rather standard theorem in our way to define basis, dimension and etc. Anyway, what you need here is only what is written above (another standard theorem): if $\;B\subset V\;$ is a l.i. set of vectors and $\;w\in V\;$ is **any** vector, then $\;B\cup\{w\}\;$ still is l.i. iff $\;w\notin Span(B)\;$ .

Comment: i see , its just that in my lecture book they proved that by induction,i think I'm just confused to when to state a definition or just prove eveything

Comment: I like this approach, with this we can prove that if $S$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $Dim(S)= Dim(V) \iff S = V$.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to prove since the dimension of $V$ is $n$ and the fact that any set of $n$ linearly independent vectors form a basis is immediately true by the [**definition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) of basis.

Notably note that any set of $n$ linearly independent vectors span $V$, indeed since $V$ has a basis of $n$ vectors if the new set didn't span $V$ we would have a contradiction.

Comment: This hardly answers the question, imo, as it is, basically, what the OP wrote.

Comment: @DonAntonio Indeed it seems a trivial fact to me but maybe I'm loosing something here! How could we elaborate e better answer?

Comment: I've already written one. But we could also argue that from definitions **and accompanying theorems**, it follows that a basis is the same as a maximal linear independent set, or a minimal spanning set...Then it'd follow at once.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank I try to improve my answer!

Comment: @gimusi maybe it was clear to you from definition as you may have just assumed n=m case from "if V vector space dimension n, then for linearly independent set S of m vectors where m<=n there exists another set R of n-m vectors such that S∪
R=basis of V" which as DonAntonio said is a standard theorem .

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with gimusi that it follows from the *definition* of "basis".  The definition of "basis" that he links to says that a basis is a set of vectors that (1) spans the space and (2) are independent.  However, it does follow from the definition of "dimension"!  It can be shown that all bases for a given vector space have the same number of members and we call that the "dimension" of the vector space.  Basically, a basis for a vector space of dimension n has three properties: (1) they span the space, (2) they are independent, and (3) there are n vectors in the set.  And if any two of those are true then the third is true!

Comment: We know that the dimension is $n$ since $V$ has a basis of size $n$, thus any set of n linearly independent vectors is a basis since it spans V, maybe we could prove why a set of n linearly independent vectors span V but sisnce V has a basis of n vectors if the new set didn't span V we should have a contradiction.